# How can I pass data from controller to form in go lang?

Tags: api, go

I have a handler / controller that takes in an http request.

```
func UpdateHandler(request *http.Request) {
    ID := mux.Vars(request)["ID"]
    UpdateForm.Save(ID,db)
}
```

Then I have a form that I want to process the data and eventually update it.

```
type UpdateForm struct {
    ID              string            `json:"type"`
}

func (UpdateForm) Save(db mongo.Database) {
    id := ID
    repository.Update(Id)
}
```

Go will print out `undefined ID`

How can I make sure that the form gets the value from the controller?

Answer (score 2):

You can populate your form using data from the request. If your request contains a JSON encoded body than you could decode it into your form object like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

type UpdateForm struct {
    ID string `json:"type"`
}

func main() {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest(
        "POST",
        "http://example.com",
        strings.NewReader(`{"type": "foo"}`),
    )

    var form *UpdateForm
    json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&form)
    fmt.Println(form.ID) // Output: foo
}
```

Or you can instantiate it directly like this:

```
func UpdateHandler(request *http.Request) {
    ID := mux.Vars(request)["ID"]
    form := &UpdateForm{ID: ID}
    form.Save()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it has nothing to do with the handler, but your code isn't consistent. This line

```
UpdateForm.Save(ID,db)
```

The method `Save()` takes two arguments, while the original method signature takes only a single `mongo.Database` type argument.

Here is what I assume was your intention:

```
type UpdateForm struct {
    ID     string   `json:"type"`
}

func (u UpdateForm) Save(db mongo.Database) {
    id := u.ID
    repository.Update(id)
}

// UpdateForm instance somewhere
var u = UpdateForm{}

func UpdateHandler(request *http.Request) {
    u.ID := mux.Vars(request)["ID"]
    u.Save(db)
}
```

Comment: Your comment about the instance "somewhere" is exactly what's killing me. Instantiated where? How can I pass data from a method in one file to another is essentially the crux of my question.

Comment: @thatgibbyguy You pass data from one method to another (or from one function to another) by calling the methods (or function) with the data as parameters. Well, that should be dead obvious. Note that Go has no "file-based boundaries" it does **not** matter in which file some method resides. (The package is important but all is fine for Exported stuff). The "instantiated somewhere" stuff: That depends, e.g in the Update handler, or in the global scope or some where else. That depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually, no the UpdateForm method should have two parameters - ID and DB because the ID should be passed to yet another function.

Comment: I was just saying your code wasn't consistent because at declaration the Save() method receives only one argument db.